# Convert form values in array

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert the following array:

```
double[] HousePriceInDollars = { 3.4, 5.2, 1.2, 0.7, 2.6, 2.7, 3.0 };
```

To a new array with Swedish prices. So it would look like this {27.2, 41.6, 9.6};

So the value of swedish is * 8 of the dollar.

How do I do this with linQ? I am kind of new to programming.

I tried this so for:

```
double[] HousePriceInDollars = { 3.4, 5.2, 1.2, 0.7, 2.6, 2.7, 3.0 };

double[] NewPriceInSek = (from f in HousePriceInDollars
                          select f)
```

Comment: So why not try for yourself?

Comment: @PatrickHofman because lot of people are willing to answer the question :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Select`:

```
double[] NewPriceInSek = HousePriceInDollars.Select(x => x * 8).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var NewPriceInSek = HousePriceInDollars.Select(d => d * 8).ToArray();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
var conversionRate = 8;
var NewPriceInSek = HousePriceInDollars.Select(x=> x*conversionRate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
double[] HousePriceInDollars = { 3.4, 5.2, 1.2, 0.7, 2.6, 2.7, 3.0 };
List<double> NewPrice = new List<double>();

foreach (var cost in HousePriceInDollars)
{
    NewPrice.Add(cost * 8);
}

double[] NewPriceInSek = NewPrice.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

And in the query expression syntax:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    { 
        double[] HousePriceInDollars = { 3.4, 5.2, 1.2, 0.7, 2.6, 2.7, 3.0 };

        var query =
            from n in HousePriceInDollars
            select n * 8;

        foreach (var item in query)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data structure is an array, you can use [`Array.ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
double[] NewPriceInSek = Array.ConvertAll(HousePriceInDollars, d => d * 8);
```